# Why is the `nm` utility named as such?

Tags: unix, command-line, linker, nm

The `nm` the utility to list symbols in a binary doesn't include in its documentation any explanation or clue of how it got to be named `nm`.

I imagine some of the long experienced UNIX developers can shed some light.

Why is the `nm` utility named as such?

Comment: I _think_ it stands for "name mangling". Not sure.

Comment: At 110 baud, it was faster to type "nm" than "name". Similarly, "ls" is faster than "list", "ld" is faster then "load", and "cc" is faster than "c". Oops. I guess my theory isn't right. ;-)

Comment: It is indeed surprising that Unix has no single-letter commands like `c`. Maybe the risk of typos was deemed to great?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "names" or "name list".

> Nm prints the name list (symbol table) of each object file in the argument list.

([V7 Unix manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nm&manpath=Unix%20Seventh%20Edition&format=ascii), 1979)

Comment: Note that [`nm` was already in Unix V1 (1971)](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/nm)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html it looks like it is an abbreviation for "NaMe list".

Answer (score 1):

Name symbols. Thus "nm" is the abbreviation chosen.